# Projective Resolution of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

> The question I have is on how to find a Projective Resolution of $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have found that $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat, but it is not projective.  I mention this as I wonder if there is some sort of trick I can use knowing that it is flat.

> I am ultimately wanting to figure out  $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^n(\mathbb{Q},B)$, respectively $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^n(\mathbb{Q/Z},B)$ for some arbitrary $\mathbb{Z}$-module $B$.

Now I know how to calculate the rest of the steps i.e. $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(_-,B)(P)$ where $P$ is the projective resolution of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q/\mathbb{Z}}$, but could use any tricks for getting the resolutions.

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: Check for a typo in your Ext.

Comment: I don't understand? If you want to calculate $\mbox{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^n(\mathbb{Z}; B)$, why don't you construct a projective resolution for $\mathbb{Z}$? Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}-$module (every unitary ring $R$ can be consider a free module over itself, with base $\{ 1 \}$), hence $\mathbb{Z}-$projective. So you can choose the 'trivial' projective resolution: $0 \to 0 \to ... \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{1_{\mathbb{Z}}} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$, shouldn't it be easier, no? :)

Comment: @user49685: as Jack Schmidt noticed there is probably a typo and what Relativeo whants to compute is $Ext^n(B,\mathbb Z)$. Interpreting litteraly the question, your comment completely answers the question...

Comment: Uhm, I think I get what you mean. Thanks. The question is not very clear itself, even if it reads as $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}; B)$, or $\text{Ext}(B; \mathbb{Z})$, projective resolutions for $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ are not very relevant at all.

Comment: yep, you are right...

Comment: @user49685, indeed, I had made an error, Simone is correct.  I fixed it.

Comment: @user49685, As for the relevance of $\mathbb{Q} \text{ and } \mathbb{Q/Z}$  I am not sure how they are relevant, however the Ext groups were asked and thus I am trying to understand and figure them out.  Most of pure math doesen't immediately seem relevant to me; if it were it would probably be in applied math ;) .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact is that $\mathbb Z$ is a hereditary ring, that is, submodules of projectives are still projectives (or, equivalently, quotients of injectives are still injective). Thus for finding a projective resolution of $\mathbb Q$ you can proceed as follows:

(1) take a surjection $f:\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb Q)}\rightarrow \mathbb Q$;

(2) the kernel of $f$ is projective as it is a submodule of a direct sum of projectives;

(3) $0\to\ker(f)\to \mathbb Z^{(\mathbb Q)}\to \mathbb Q\to 0$ is a projective resolution.

For computing $\mathrm{Ext}$, you can notice by the above argument that higer ext's are always trivial on hereditary rings...

It is also easy to find an injective resolution for $\mathbb Z$ (and you can use that to compute the $\mathrm{Ext}$-groups):

$$0\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to 0$$

Comment: I see that $0\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to 0$ is an injective resolution but am unsure as to why I can take the injective resolution instead of the projective resolution of $ \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Well, in principle $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(-,-)$ is a functor from $Ab\times Ab$ to $Ab$, in particular it sends an ordered pair $(A,B)$ of Abelian groups to an Abelian group $Hom(A,B)$. Now, in order to construct its derived functors you just fix one of the two entries (say $A$) obtaining a functor $Hom(A,-):Ab\to Ab$. This gives you a left exact functor, to compute its derived functors you have to take an injective resolution of $B$ and proceed as you probably know. Of course there is another possibility, that is, fixing $B$ you have a right exact contravariant functor $Hom(-,B):Ab\to Ab$. [...]

Comment: To construct the derived functors of this second functor you shuold construct a projective resolution of $A$ and then proceed as you know. Now, it is a standard result (but not completely trivial... you should check it) that the two constructions give you the same out-put when you use them to construct $Ext^{n}(A,B)$. 

As Jack Schmidt was telling you in his comment, there is a mistake in your question, in the sense that, being $\mathbb Z$ a projective object, the $Ext$-groups $Ext^n(\mathbb Z,B)$ that you want to construct are always trivial [...]

Comment: (a part $n=0$ when $Ext^0(\mathbb Z,B)=Hom(\mathbb Z,B)\cong B$). The interesting thing is to compute $Hom(B,\mathbb Z)$, for which you can use the injective resolution I have written in my answer.

Comment: How would one determine the kernel of $f$? If we say $f:a^{b/c}\mapsto b/c$ we have that $ker(f)=\{a^{b/c} :  a=0\}$ which I guess is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or maybe $\{0\}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ which I'm note sure what is isomorphic to. Hope one can explain

Comment: Well, $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ is a subgroup of a free Abelian group, so in particular it is free and, in order to completely determine it, it is enough to find a basis. On the other hand, the usual ways to find such bases are non-constructive (see the standard proofs that subgroups of free groups are free). In this special case there may be a way to be more explicit (I did not try to work out the details): fix an explicit bijection $\mathbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ from $\mathbb Q$ to the naturals, then find a vector $v_1$ that generates $\mathrm{Ker}(f)\cap \mathbb Z^{(q_0,q_1)}$....

Comment: Proceed inductively to find, for each $n>1$, an element $v_n\in \mathrm{Ker}(f)\cap \mathbb Z^{(q_0,\dots,q_n)}$, such that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of this intersection. Then, $\{v_1,\dots,v_n,\dots\}$ should be a basis of $\bigcup_{\mathbb N}\mathrm{Ker}(f)\cap \mathbb Z^{(q_0,\dots,q_n)}=\mathrm {Ker}(f)$.

Comment: Anyway, the important thing is that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ is projective, and it is easily seen to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)}$. Finally, take into account the last part of my answer: it is much easier in this case to compute extensions using injective resolutions!

Comment: To see that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)\cong\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)}$, just note that, for any finite subset $F\subseteq \mathbb Q$,  $\mathrm {rank}(\mathrm{Ker}(f)\cap \mathbb Z^{(F)})=\mathrm{rank}(\mathbb Z^{(F)})-\mathrm{rank}(f(\mathbb Z^{(F)}))=|F|-1$, so $\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{Ker}(f))=\mathrm{sup}\{|F|-1:F\subseteq\mathbb Q\text{ finite}\}=|\mathbb N|$ (where, by definition, $\mathrm {rank}(G):=\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb Q}(\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}G)$, for any Abelian group $G$).